# What are the best practices when working with data from multiple sources in Flutter/Bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

The Bloc manual describes [the example of a simple Todos app](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial). It works as an example, but I get stuck when trying to make it into a more realistic app. Clearly, a more realistic Todos app needs to keep working when the user temporarily loses network connection, and also needs to occasionally check the server for updates that the user might have added from another device.

So as a basic data model I have:

- `dataFromServer`, which is refreshed every five minutes, and
- `localData`, that describes what changes have been made locally but haven't been synchronized to the server yet.

My current idea is to have three kinds of events:

- `on<GetTodosFromServer>()` which runs every few minutes to check the server for updates and only changes the `dataFromServer`,
- `on<TodoAdded>()` (and its friends `TodoDeleted`, `TodoChecked`, and so on) which get triggered when the user changes the data, and only change the `localData`, and
- `on<SyncTodoToServer>()` which runs whenever the user changes the todo list, or when network connectivity is restored, and tries to send the changes to the server, retrieves the new value from the server, and then sets the new `dataFromServer` and `localData`.

So obviously there's a lot of interaction between these three methods. When a new todo is added after the synchronization to the server starts, but before synchronization is finished, it needs to stay in the local changes object. When GetTodosFromServer and SyncTodoToServer both return server data, they need to find out who has the latest data and keep that. And so on.

Coming from a Redux background, I'm used to having two reducers (one for local data, one for server data) that would only respond to simple actions. E.g. an action `{ "type": "TodoSuccessfullySyncedToServer", uploadedData: [...], serverResponse: [...] }` would be straightforward to parse for both the `localData` and the `dataFromServer` reducer. The reducer doesn't contain any of the business logic, it receives actions one by one and all you need to think about inside the reducer is the state before the action, the action itself, and the state after the action. Anything you rely on to handle the action will be in the action itself, not in the context. So different pieces of code that generate those actions can just fire these actions without thinking, knowing that the reducer will handle them correctly.

Bloc on the other hand seems to mix business logic and updating the state. API calls are made within the event handlers, which will emit a value possibly many seconds later. So every time you return from an asynchronous call in an event handler, you need to think about how the state might have changed while that call was happening and the consequences this has on what you're currently doing. Also, an object in the state can be updated by different events that need to coordinate among themselves how to avoid conflicts while doing so.

Is there a best practice on how to avoid the complexity that brings? Is it best practice to split large events into "StartSyncToServer" and "SuccessfullySyncedToServer" events where the second behaves a lot like a Redux reducer? I don't see any of that in the examples, so is there another way this complexity is typically avoided in Bloc? Or is Bloc entirely unopinionated on these things?

I'm not looking for personal opinions here, only if there's something I missed in the Bloc manual (or other authoritative source) about how this was intended to work.